# Disabling colored borders in pdf with bookmark package

Tags: color, bookmarks

How do I get rid of the very ugly and annoying colored borders around all text in my pfd that is bookmarked?

I am not using the hyperref package to make the bookmarks, because I cannot get than compiled for some unknown reason, but I use the bookmark package. I load this package in the preamble with the following line:

```
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
```

Is there an option that I can add to this line to remove both the borders and colors in my pfd? Something like "*pdfborder={0 0 0}*" or "*colorlinks=false*" (used with the hyperref package).

Thanks!

Comment: bookmarks loads hyperref as far as I can see, are you sure you are not using it? `\hypersetup{colorlinks=...` ought to work

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  I think it is up to the particular PDF viewer as to select how bookmarks/links are displayed.

Answer (score 4):

Adding

`\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`

before

`\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}`

Gets rid of the color boxes. However, my Figure numbers and captions are vertically offset from each other by about half a line...

Comment: So you're playing wack-a-mole here? Fixing something on one end, but causing a problem elsewhere? If so, then this is not a good answer.

Comment: @Werner: Is it an answer then? ;-)

Comment: It could be a piece of the answer.  My issue could be related to the style file, or my long caption (6 plots in one figure taking a whole page...), and thus the issue I am having may not occur for other people.  I am curious to see what people say.

Answer (score 0):

```
%%Use this code in your preamble:

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark} %%for fancy bookmarking with no initial numbering
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can encapsulate your code using a tick for inline or three ticks for multiline.

Comment: Welcome to TeX S.E. Didn’T test your answer, but you shouldn't call twice the same package. `\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}` should be used AFAIK. Also provide a fully compiliable MWE, please.